# Specifically RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}

Tags: regex, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

Hello I have a peculiar problem: I was tasked with redirecting a WP page (page_id=2) to to the page (about) on the same domain, however when I use the string redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/about? [R=301,L]
```

...it redirects all `pages page_id=2` that are located on the site like

`en/?page_id=2 , ok/?page_id=2 , en/ok/?page_id=2`

Is there a way to specifically redirect only the "root" page `page_id=2` and leave the other as they are?

And what about if in the future i want to redirect some of the sub pages for example `en/ok/?page_id=2` to `en/ok/about`?

Sorry for my bad English - if I can provide additional clarification, please ask away.

Comment: does anyone have any tips ? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a rewrite condition based on request URI:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=2$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/about? [R=301,L]
```

In future, when you want to append about to all pages, you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/about? [R=301,L]
```